# Replicate rows with missing values and replace missing values by vector

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, row, replicate

I have a dataframe in which a column has some missing values.
I would like to replicate the rows with the missing values N times, where N is the length of a vector which contains replacements for the missing values.

I first define a replacement vector, then my starting data.frame, then my desired result and finally my attempt to solve it. Unfortunately that didn't work...

```
> replace_values <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
> data.frame(value = c(3, 4, NA, NA), result = c(5, 3, 1,2))
  value result
1     3      5
2     4      3
3    NA      1
4    NA      2
> data.frame(value = c(3, 4, replace_values, replace_values), result = c(5, 3, rep(1, 3),rep(2, 3)))
  value result
1     3      5
2     4      3
3     A      1
4     B      1
5     C      1
6     A      2
7     B      2
8     C      2
> t <- data.frame(value = c(3, 4, NA, NA), result = c(5, 3, 1,2))
> mutate(t, value = ifelse(is.na(value), replace_values, value))
  value result
1     3      5
2     4      3
3     C      1
4     A      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
d %>% 
  mutate(value=ifelse(is.na(value), paste0(replace_values, collapse=","), value)) %>% 
  separate_rows(value, sep=",") %>% 
  select(value, everything())
  value result
1     3      5
2     4      3
3     A      1
4     B      1
5     C      1
6     A      2
7     B      2
8     C      2
```

The idea is to replace the `NA`'s by the `,`-collapsed 'replace_values'. Then separate the collpased values and binding them by row using `tidyr`'s `separate_rows` function. Finally sort the `data.frame` according your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

We can do an `rbind` here using `base R`.  Create a logical vector where the 'value' is NA ('i1'), get the number of NA elements by taking the `sum` of it ('n'), create a `data.frame` by `rep`licating the 'replace_values' with 'n' as well as the 'result' elements that correspond to the NA elements of 'value' by the `length` of 'replace_values' and 'rbind' with the subset of dataset i.e. the non-NA elements of 'value' rows

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$value)
n <- sum(i1)
rbind(df1[!i1,], 
   data.frame(value = rep(replace_values, n), 
    result = rep(df1$result[i1], each = length(replace_values))))
#   value result
#1     3      5
#2     4      3
#3     A      1
#4     B      1
#5     C      1
#6     A      2
#7     B      2
#8     C      2
```